# Converting encoded utf-8 JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, utf-8

I'm using this PHP code to generate the JSON from MySQL database:

```
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
$emparray[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
        }
        echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Then I use the HttpUrlConnection to fetch the url and get the Echo string:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://localhost/myserver.php");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
```

the print is:

```
[{"id":"1","titulo":"C\u00f3digo de Defesa do Consumidor","descricao":"Institui o c\u00f3digo de defesa do consumidor","tags":"cdc","categorias":"cat_cod,cat_leisord","numero_da_lei":"13105","data_da_lei":"11111111","ativa":"1","byuser":"0","versao_da_lei":"0","url":"http:\/\/www.planalto.gov.br\/ccivil_03\/leis\/L8078compilado.htm"}]
```

I know that the output is encoded because I have `$emparray[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);` but if I do not use this, the text that has special chars becomes NULL.

How can I convert

```
"titulo":"C\u00f3digo de Defesa do Consumidor"
```

to

```
"titulo":"Código de Defesa do Consumidor"
```

I've tried:

```
 new String(result.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

but nothing changed

Comment: try set header of your `myserver.php` as `header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');` write this line at top (first line)

Comment: How about using `mysql_set_charset` or `mysqli::set_charset` to set UTF-8 as the default character set for all MySQL connections?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Don't use utf8 encoders/decoders.  Instead have utf8 everywhere.  Where did "unicode" `\u00f3` come from?  Go back before that and change it to be "utf8".

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringEscapeUtils Apache Library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

For saving the unicodes in database you have to encode them. So send your unicodes to server by encoding like

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("Código de Defesa do Consumidor")
```

For displaying the encoded unicode in android

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("C\u00f3digo de Defesa do Consumidor")
```